# How is unicode or any other coding data stored in memory? (win32)

Tags: c++, c, winapi, unicode

Sorry for this amateurish question, I want to do some search and comparisions within an unicode string.

I am a little bit confused about `unicode-16`/`wchar_t`, in windows OS, does this stored the same way as an array of `uint16`?

I mean if I can use it this way without any trouble?

```
wchar_t a[100]; 
somefunction((uint16 *)a);
//treat a as an array of uint16 data and do something with it.
```

Comment: On Windows, yes.  If you want to be more portable, check out `std::wstring_convert`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/wstring_convert

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it's an array of `wchar_t`, which is a `uint16_t`.  It's also (usually) NUL-terminated, meaning there's a zero-valued `wchar_t` at the end of the string.

Comment: Thanks, so the wchar_t array a in the above example is actually an array of 101 words(16-bit) in memory, althrough to be programmer, usually only the first 100 words is avaliable?

Comment: Yes, but be aware that it is platform specific, i.e. it is only on Windows with Microsoft Compilers. Most Unices and even gcc on cygwin have `wchar_t` defined as `uint32_t`.

Comment: @user2188453: No, it's an array of 100 words, of which up to 99 can contain your text, and the one following the last character of text should be zero.

Comment: @tristopia, thanks, can you tell me if ICC (targeting windows platform) treat wchar_t as uint32 or uint16?

Comment: @user2188453: If you need to know, the proper solution is to compare `sizeof(wchar_t)` with `sizeof(uint32_t)`